# jquery .on not working after other .on call

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following jquery script:

```
$(function(){   
$('#top-menu').on('click', 'a.change-menu', function(e){   
e.preventDefault()   
$("#menu-change-div").load($(this).attr("href"));   

});  
}); 

$(function(){   
$('#menu-change-div').on('click', 'a.change-content', function(e){     
e.preventDefault()   
$("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));     
});  
});
```

Here's the HTML inside the body:

```
<div id="menu-div">
<div id="top-menu">
<h3 id="top-tabs"><a href="contentColumn.html" class="change-menu">Contents</a></h3>
<h3 id="top-tabs"><a href="indexColumn.html" class="change-menu">Index</a></h3>
<h3 id="top-tabs"><a href="searchColumn.html" class="change-menu">Search</a></h3>
</div>
<div id="menu-change-div">
<ul>
//Lots of nested list items and ul's with #change-content id
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id = "page-content">
//content section
</div>
</div>
```

The first function occurs when I click a list item in my menu div and loads an html file into my content div.

The second one changes whats in my menu div when a different tab is selected.

I can click list item and everything works as expected and when I click the tabs it also works properly.  My problem is occuring if I first click a list item, then click a tab, then click another list item. Instead of just loading the html into the div like it did on the first click, it instead just follows the href and opens it in another window.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Neither of those `.on()` calls are using delegation, which means when the elements that they are binding to are replaced/removed, the events will no longer happen. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.change-content', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
    $('body').on('click', 'a.change-menu', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#menu-change-div").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});​
```

if elements are being added dynamically, then you need to change the way you're using .on().

Per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Also note that you can combine your two `$(function () {...})` into one.

Comment: There's a better element other than body. It's like globals or singletons in a way.

Comment: I agree. However without any of the HTML I can only provide body as a guarantee.

Comment: absolutely, maybe add that to your answer. +1 either way

Comment: In that case you could use `document`, which is what `.live` delegates to. It's guaranteed to work anywhere in code as well (as in, before domready). :P

Comment: yea items are being added dynamically, when I change tabs the list elements in my menu div change.

Comment: your solution loads the html files in a new windown as well, not in the #content or #menu-change-div

Comment: You'll need to add the HTML you're applying the jQuery to your original question.

Comment: I updated the question and changed the script to where I'm currently at. Now its loading in the div when I follow the click squence outlined above. However, it is sometimes duplicating my menu-change-div

Answer (score 1):

> The second one changes whats in my menu div when a different tab is
>   selected.

Then the chances are you need to delegate your second `click` event handler to an ancestor element that is going to stay in the DOM. You can do this by passing a selector to the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("#someAncestor").on("click", "a.change-menu", function(e) {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This is because when you change the elements referred to by `a.change-menu`, the elements to which the event handler was bound no longer exist (new elements don't automatically get the event handler bound to them).

By delegating the event handler higher up the DOM tree, you take advantage of the fact that most DOM events bubble up the tree, and you listen for that event on an ancestor element. If the event target matches the selector passed to `on`, the event handler is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The .on() method is listening on DOM elements already there. If you add some new elements, they will not be listened. If you need to listen those elements even if they are added latter (with the .load() for example), use the .live() method.

Comment: `.on` is overloaded to do delegation/direct binding depending on arguments. `.live` is deprecated.